# couldn't open database (Android Studio)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i am here as a newbie on Android Programming.
Here i want to make an app that can note all of our cashflow.
But i have some problem when i want to make a Spinner that have value from Database.
When i run the program, report section in Android Studio give me a report "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database",
I have a little bit frustrating about this error. I have googling for it but still cant find a way to solve or maybe because i didn't understand what the tutorial says. Please master help me to solve this error with a simple word.
Thanks a lot.

NB. This is the source code for Main_Activity (Where the spinner is create)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static Button BtnINewTrans;
private static Button BtnIViewCash;
private static Button BtnIAddCateg;
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
Spinner selectCategory;
//ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCategory;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    onButtonClickButtonListener();
    select_spinner_Category();


}

/*ArrayList<String> my_array = new ArrayList<String>();
my_array = getTableValues();

Spinner My_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, my_array);
My_spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);*/

public void select_spinner_Category (){
    ArrayList<String> arrayCategory = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayCategory = dbHelper.getAllCategory();
    selectCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCategSelect);
    ArrayAdapter adapterCategory  = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayCategory);
   // adapterCategory = new ArrayList<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.id.spnCategSelect, AllCategoryList);
    adapterCategory.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    selectCategory.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
    selectCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}

public void onButtonClickButtonListener(){
    BtnINewTrans = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNewTrans);
    BtnINewTrans.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentNewTrans = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.NewTransaction");
                    startActivity(intentNewTrans);
                }
            }
    );

    BtnIViewCash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewCashflow);
    BtnIViewCash.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentViewCash = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.ViewCashflow");
                    startActivity(intentViewCash);
                }
            }
    );

    BtnIAddCateg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddCateg);
    BtnIAddCateg.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentAddCateg = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.AddCategory");
                    startActivity(intentAddCateg);
                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And this one for Database_Helper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String MyVillageSoftware = "MyVillageSoftware";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Cashflow.db";
public static final String TABLE_Categ_NAME = "category_table";
public static final String COL1 = "CategId";
public static final String COL2 = "CategName";
public static final String COL3 = "Note";
public static final String COL4 = "Currency";
SQLiteDatabase db;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);


}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_Categ_NAME +
            " (CategID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "CategName Text," +
            " Note Text," +
            " Currency Text)");

}

public boolean insertCategData(String categname, String note, String currency){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, categname);
    contentValues.put(COL3, note);
    contentValues.put(COL4, currency);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_Categ_NAME, null, contentValues);
     if (result == 1)
         return true;
     else
         return false;

}

public ArrayList<String> getAllCategory() {

    ArrayList<String> AllCategoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null, null);
        Cursor allrows = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_Categ_NAME, null);
        System.out.println("COUNT : " + allrows.getCount());

        if (allrows.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String ID = allrows.getString(0);
                String Categ = allrows.getString(1);
                String Note = allrows.getString(2);
                String Curr = allrows.getString(3);
                AllCategoryList.add(Categ);

            } while (allrows.moveToNext());
        }
        allrows.close();
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {


    }
    return AllCategoryList;
}

/*public ArrayList<String>getAllCategory(){
    ArrayList<String> AllCategoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectCateg="Select * FROM " +TABLE_Categ_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectCateg, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String categname1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL2));
            AllCategoryList.add(COL2);

        }return AllCategoryList;
    }

    return AllCategoryList;

}*/


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_Categ_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

}

Comment: please send your complete log. I think database is not created successfully.

Comment: When you say it is no able to create successfully, you have to look to the logs which will give an idea of which line of execution created this issue.

Comment: i think the database is already created successfully, because i try to get the database from Android Studio using Android Device Monitor and i open it. When it opened, i run the select command, and the database that inserted is listing there.

Answer (score 0):

1. at first create DBHelper class.

   public class DBAdapter {
       private DBHelper dbHelper;
       private Context context;
       private SQLiteDatabase db;

   ```
   public DBAdapter(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
       dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
   }

   public void open() {
       db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   public void close() {
       db.close();
   }

   public long insertBook(Book book) {
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(DBHelper.TITLE, book.getTitle());
       values.put(DBHelper.AUTHOR, book.getAuthor());
       values.put(DBHelper.CATEGORY, book.getCategory());
       values.put(DBHelper.ISBN, book.getISBN());
       values.put(DBHelper.PRICE, book.getPrice());

       long inserted = db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

       return inserted;
   }

   public ArrayList<Book> getAllBooks() {
       ArrayList<Book> allBooks = null;
       String[] columns = { DBHelper.TITLE, DBHelper.AUTHOR };

       Cursor cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null,
               null, null);
       // select * from books;
       if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
           int size = cursor.getCount();
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           allBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
               String title = cursor.getString(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TITLE));
               String author = cursor.getString(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.AUTHOR));
               String category = cursor.getString(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CATEGORY));
               String ISBN = cursor.getString(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ISBN));
               double price = cursor.getDouble(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PRICE));
               allBooks.add(new Book(title, author, category, ISBN, price));
               cursor.moveToNext();
           }
       }

       cursor.close();

       return allBooks;
   }
   ```

   }
2. then create DBAdapter

   ```
   public class DBAdapter {
   private DBHelper dbHelper;
   private Context context;
   private SQLiteDatabase db;

   public DBAdapter(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
       dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
   }

   public void open() {
       db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   public void close() {
       db.close();
   }

   public long insertBook(Book book) {
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(DBHelper.TITLE, book.getTitle());
       values.put(DBHelper.AUTHOR, book.getAuthor());
       values.put(DBHelper.CATEGORY, book.getCategory());
       values.put(DBHelper.ISBN, book.getISBN());
       values.put(DBHelper.PRICE, book.getPrice());

       long inserted = db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

       return inserted;
   }

   public ArrayList<Book> getAllBooks() {
       ArrayList<Book> allBooks = null;
       String[] columns = { DBHelper.TITLE, DBHelper.AUTHOR };

       Cursor cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null,
               null, null);
       // select * from books;
       if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
           int size = cursor.getCount();
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           allBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
               String title = cursor.getString(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TITLE));
               String author = cursor.getString(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.AUTHOR));
               String category = cursor.getString(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CATEGORY));
               String ISBN = cursor.getString(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ISBN));
               double price = cursor.getDouble(cursor
                       .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PRICE));
               allBooks.add(new Book(title, author, category, ISBN, price));
               cursor.moveToNext();
           }
       }

       cursor.close();

       return allBooks;
   }
   ```

   }

DBAdapter  class create a object in DBhelper class and open android database of exit otherwise it create a new database .

3. finally can get data form data database this way

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   private EditText etTitle, etAuthor, etCategory, etISBN, etPrice;
   private Button btnSave, btnView;
   private DBAdapter dbAdapter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
       etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
       etAuthor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAuthor);
       etCategory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCategory);
       etISBN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etISBN);
       etPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrice);

       btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
       btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
       btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
       btnView.setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.btnSave:
           String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
           String author = etAuthor.getText().toString();
           String category = etCategory.getText().toString();
           String ISBN = etISBN.getText().toString();
           double price = Double.parseDouble(etPrice.getText().toString());

           dbAdapter.open();
           long inserted = dbAdapter.insertBook(new Book(title, author,
                   category, ISBN, price));
           dbAdapter.close();

           if (inserted >= 0) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert Successful",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

           break;
       case R.id.btnView:
           // retrieve a list of books
           dbAdapter.open();
           ArrayList<Book> books = dbAdapter.getAllBooks();
           dbAdapter.close();
           for (Book book : books) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), book.toString(),
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           // view
           break;

       default:
           break;
       }

   }
   ```

   }

////////////////////////

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String category;
    private String ISBN;
    private double price;

    public Book(String title, String author, String category, String iSBN,
            double price) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.category = category;
        ISBN = iSBN;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getISBN() {
        return ISBN;
    }

    public void setISBN(String iSBN) {
        ISBN = iSBN;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[" + title + " " + author + " " + category + " " + ISBN + " "
                + price + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: i am sorry sir, i have try that rule for my code, but the error report still there.
Can you show me where is my database helper is not called right way?? thanks

Comment: can you gimme your email address sir??